# javascript make space around image grey

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my page if the user clicks a button an image will apear in the middle of the page. Now I want additionally that the space around the image (the entire remaining page) will appear grey. I tried the following code, but it won't work.

```
function showLoading(){
    $.blockUI({ css: { 
        border: 'none', 
        padding: '15px', 
        backgroundColor: '#000', 
        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
        '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
        opacity: .5, 
        color: '#fff' 
    } }); 
document.getElementById("loading").style["visibility"] = "visible";
}
```

The jquery Code will not be executed. How can I execute this in javascript? I tried to use `write.line("<style>...</style>")`, but this work neither.

Comment: providing a jsfiddle might be beneficial here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make div for that with absolute position change z-index as per your requirement

```
<div id="overlay" style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;z-index:100;display:none;background-color:#000;opacity:.5"></div>
```

when click the button it become show

```
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display="block";
```

add this line on your function

Comment: This works, but the image is in the background, and this should actually be in foreground.

Comment: add z-index in your image : z-index:200